# Correlation in forecast error

Tags: time-series, statistics, correlation, forecasting, hypothesis-testing

I am working on a time series project and while calculating the prediction intervals using bootstrapping method I have to fulfill the assumptions of it. It has an assumption of uncorrelated forecast error. So, I want to know Which test is appropriate to test that forecast errors are uncorrelated?